# how to use MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate

Tags: entity-framework

I know this has been covered to some extend in other chains, but even after interpolating it to my needs, I'm still having issues. As many of you know documentation is virtually non-existent. Therefore, any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to create a generic method which merely generates a DB script from a DLL containing EF entities. Then, I pass a DLL path and a name of the connection string defined in App.config. The first time through, the script is generated fine. I run it in SQLServer Studio and it generates all the tables, etc. However, when I run it the 2nd time (DB exists), it fails on the ScriptUpdate method with the following error:

Failed to set database initializer of type 'Disabled' for DbContext type 'AdminovateLibrary.Repository.EntityDbContext, Adminovate.AdminovateLibrary-Project' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.

Inner exception is: "Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"MyLibrary".

I assume that if the DLL contains exactly the same code as in the 1st run, the method should product an empty string. However, even if I run it with a modified DLL, it gives me the same error.

My code is as follows:

```
    public string GenerateUpdateSchemaScript( string sourceDllFilePath, string targetConnectionName ) {
        var dbMigrationsConfiguration = CreateConfiguration( sourceDllFilePath, targetConnectionName );
        var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator( dbMigrationsConfiguration );

        Database.SetInitializer( new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DbContext>() );

        var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator( dbMigrator );
        var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate( null, null );
        return RemoveCreateMigrationHistoryTable( dbMigrationsConfiguration, script );
    }

    private static DbMigrationsConfiguration CreateConfiguration2( string sourceDllFilePath, string targetConnectionName ) {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( sourceDllFilePath );
        var configType = assembly.GetTypes().Single( type => typeof( DbMigrationsConfiguration ).IsAssignableFrom( type ) );
        var configuration = ( DbMigrationsConfiguration )assembly.CreateInstance( configType.FullName );
        if( configuration != null ) {
            configuration.ContextType = assembly.GetTypes().Single( type => type.BaseType == typeof( DbContext ) );
            configuration.MigrationsAssembly = assembly;
            configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo( targetConnectionName );
            configuration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }
        return configuration;
    }
```